# How to break do-while loop on button

Tags: button, javafx, do-while, break

Currently i have two problems with this case:

1. Im trying to find a way to break the infinite loop after cancelButton is clicked.  I was trying to set the variable flag to false when the button is clicked and set the flag variable as condition in the loop but i cannot achieve this.
2. The second issue is. How to initialize two separate arraylist from this dialog window. In example its returning a Pair of Strings. I would like the values to be added in a loop to an ArrayLists.

   ```
   import javafx.application.Platform;
   import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
   import javafx.geometry.Insets;
   import javafx.scene.Node;
   import javafx.scene.control.*;
   import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
   import javafx.util.Pair;
   import javafx.scene.control.Label;


   import java.util.*;

   public class Controller {
   public void pick (ActionEvent event) {


   boolean flag = true;

   do {


       // Create the custom dialog.
       Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
       dialog.setTitle("Login Dialog");
       dialog.setHeaderText("Look, a Custom Login Dialog");


       //Set the button types.
       ButtonType dalejButtonType = new ButtonType("Dalej", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
       ButtonType cancelButton = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
       dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(dalejButtonType, cancelButton);


       // Create the username and password labels and fields.
       GridPane grid = new GridPane();
       grid.setHgap(10);
       grid.setVgap(10);
       grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

       TextField imie = new TextField();
       imie.setPromptText("Imię");
       TextField email = new TextField();
       email.setPromptText("eMail");

       grid.add(new Label("Imię:"), 0, 0);
       grid.add(imie, 1, 0);
       grid.add(new Label("eMail:"), 0, 1);
       grid.add(email, 1, 1);

       // Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
       Node loginButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(dalejButtonType);
       loginButton.setDisable(true);

       // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
       imie.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
           loginButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
       });

       dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

       // Request focus on the username field by default.
       Platform.runLater(() -> imie.requestFocus());

       // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
       dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
           if (dialogButton == dalejButtonType) {
               return new Pair<>(imie.getText(), email.getText());
           }


           return null;


       });


       Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();


   } while(flag);
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I think the surrounding of all method into `do/while` is not good idea. In this case you create the dialog with all elements every time. Not good for performance. Will be better if you loop only the showing of the dialog.

About the second question about lists: you may create such lists and populate in the converter. In this case `do/while` can be simplified to `while` with checking only for result presenting:

```
    final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
    dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
        if (dialogButton == dalejButtonType) {
            names.add(imie.getText());
            emails.add(email.getText());
            return new Pair<>(imie.getText(), email.getText());
        }

        return null;
    });

    while(dialog.showAndWait().isPresent()) {
        // do additional something if needed
    }
```

An alternative solution where the lists are populated in `do/while` but without `flag`:

```
    Optional<Pair<String, String>> result;
    do{
        result = dialog.showAndWait();

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            names.add(result.get().getKey());
            emails.add(result.get().getValue());
        }
    } while(result.isPresent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work to do

```
if (result.isPresent()) {
    Pair<String, String> values = result.get();
    // add values to list
} else {
    flag = false ;
}
```

?